Putty Fatal Error: erver refused our key
I am establish an ssh connect from putty 0.81 to connect to the free oracle cloud ec2
I receive the following error when using PuTTY Release 0.74 Build platform: 64-bit x86 Windows: "No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey, gssapi-keyex, gssapi-with-mic)"
This is what I did:
Generate the pair public_key & private_key during the oracle ol8 creation.
I generated the private key from puttygent and in the putty.
Insert server's IP address and port in "Session"
Insert the path to my locally saved private_key in "Connection -> SSH -> Auth -> Credentials"
Save the whole configuration
Finally, if I load the configuration and try to open the connection, it prompted me for the login and after enter the user:opc
I receive the error message Server refused our key
and Putty Fatal Error: No supported authentication methods available (server sent:publickey.gssapi-keyex.gssapi-with-mic)
How to correct and connect to the linux OL8 from Window putty?
I tried using MobaXterm and get the same error, No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Did you generate keys only in PuTTYgen, or did you also generate a separate keypair at Oracle Cloud? Are you sure you're using PuTTY 0.81, if your error message says "PuTTY 0.74"? At which step did you upload the public key from PuTTYgen to the server?

no, i used the private key generate from oracle cloud.  I rebuilt the machine and restarted from fresh and load the private key from oracle cloud built.  It connected now. Don't know I can use the same for new machine connection or not.
Thank you.
